# where can I find Tizen OS statistics

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk

Is there any link / graph or etc. about statistics of usage Tizen OS on wearables? If I want to develop Tizen wearable App, what version should I use for biggest part of Tizen Wearable devices?

Answer (score 0):

You could target your app for most smartwatches with little to no modifications, starting from 
Galaxy Watch, Gear Sport, S3 Series, S2 Series (they all run Tizen, albeit different versions)

Most APIs (web or native) are backward compatible or are gracefully deprecated and the amount of work required to adapt across models, would depend on the platform features the app depends on.

Given a choice, I would target my app for the 'Galaxy Watch' or Gear Sport, considering software upgrade cycles.

I couldn't find OS usage statistics. Googling provides [links](https://www.statista.com/statistics/524830/global-smartwatch-vendors-market-share/), for figures of market share.